# Spring cloud bus with EnableBinding (non functional approach)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

- I use spring boot `2.7.2` and spring cloud dependencies `2021.0.3`.
- The project uses  annotation-based model (`EnableBinding`) rather than
  functional. That's something I cannot change.
- Right now the bus (used for getting refresh events from config server)
  is not working due to: `Functional binding is disabled due to the presense of @EnableBinding annotation in your configuration`

The question is, if it is possible to have spring-cloud-bus configured without functional approach ?

Comment: I don't get it. You are saying you want to use `EnableBinding`, so by its presence functional binding is disabled which is based on your description is what you want and what that message tells you. What am I missing?

Comment: You're right. But I would have had to configure multiple things by myself [because there wasn't autoconfiguration for non-functional approach, only for functional]. Long story short, I just used the version `2.2.1.RELEASE` with old approach with `BusAutoConfiguration` class providing me with non-functional auto configuration out of the box. That way, everything (like connection, channels for input/output, acks etc. is configured automatically). So I think the question is ready to be closed. Nevertheless thank you for you're response Sir, I appreciate it.